# CSV upload with no set format before upload

Tags: python, django

I'm using [Django adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it works very well however, I'm starting to see CSV uploads where the user can decide what column the data belongs to after upload with no set format before upload.

**Would it be possible to build this into Django Adaptors, if so could some point me in the right direction?**

Or

**Is there any app out there that could do this?** (I have searched, with no joy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit from CSVModel class and extend/overwrite get_fields method (and other methods if needed). This is common pattern for dynamic building instances of declarative classes.

[Take a look on this code](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/blob/master/oscar/apps/dashboard/catalogue/forms.py)

ProductForm class, this is not exactly your case, but the point is the same.