# Is it possible to hide/make readonly form fields based on permisions check

Tags: django, django-forms

The basic idea is to be able to hide some form fields based on model permissions check (using class-based generic views). It is clear that I can override view's `get` and `post` to check form permissions and construct the form, but aren't there a neater way to achieve this?

So far, the view and form are pretty straightforward

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = "profile/update.html"
    form_class = UserProfileForm


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, can_change_position=False, can_change_manager=False, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._process_permission('position', can_change_position)
    self._process_permission('manager', can_change_manager)

def _process_permission(self, field, permitted):
    if permitted:
        self.fields.append(field)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', ...]
```

Am I missing something obvious, or just following the wrong way?

**Updated** looks like my intention was not clear. There was an error in the code I've posted, so the answers given so far is how to fix the error. I've fixed it already, but the question was not about how to add/remove fields on the form at run time (it's obvious). The question is, are there any way to add/remove fields based on `request` values (e.g. `request.user`) using the class-based generic views.

So, again, straightforward approach is to overload `get` and `post` on the view, perform the checks and instantiate the form. But it's somewhat repeating the existing django behavior (i.e. admin views pass `request` to `get_form`). So, aren't there a cleaner way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `__init__` method is called after `__new__` method, which actually uses 'Meta.exclude' property. (when this declarative properties to dynamic class magic happens)

Take a look at [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py) line 198.
So at the runtime you already have all instance variables.

Solution for similar problem, I have posted here:

[CSV upload with no set format before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978503/csv-upload-with-no-set-format-before-upload/15980465#15980465)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Attributes named `base_fields` is set on the form class itself, which in your case is `UserProfileForm`. When you create an instance of this form i.e `UserProfileForm()`, an attribute named `fields` is set on form instances which is copy of `base_fields` available on form class.

And `base_fields` is set in the metaclass and normally you would not like to change metaclass. Also, `Meta.exclude` and `Meta.fields` are used in the metaclass' `__new__`, so changing them in `__init__` of form will not have any effect.

So, what you can do is to remove the fields which you do not want from attribute `fields` of form instance in `__init__`.

Code:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, can_change_position=False, can_change_manager=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._process_permission('position', can_change_position)
        self._process_permission('manager', can_change_manager)         

    def _process_permission(self, field, permitted):
        if not permitted and field in self.fields:
            del self.fields[field]
```